# Why do some applications stop working when permissions are changed in /usr/bin?

Tags: permissions, osx, crash

On OS X, a friend of mine changed the permissions on `/usr/bin` recursively using Finder, in order to grand write access to everyone.

Here is how it's done:

Go to `/usr/bin` in Finder, then mess with the permissions at the bottom of the info window:

[image: Finder change permissions]

After that, you can no longer run `Terminal.app` for example. But you can still run Disk Utility, which is needed to recover from this without a terminal.

Here is the error that you have in this case:

```
Last login: Fri Jul  4 15:39:24 on ttys001
login(27006,0x7fff78115310) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fceb3412cc0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Luckily, I quickly found a question mentioning this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329005/mac-terminal-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-error-when-opening-terminal).

My first thought was that this is a hardware problem (maybe some random corruption on the hard drive / in RAM / etc..).

How is this error related to the wrong permissions in `/usr/bin`?

While trying to work on the broken system to get a clean difference listing, I got this:

```
$ sudo -s
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
```

Here is the result of `diskutil verifyPermissions` (which solves the problem BTW):

(Too big to be posted here)

Each line is of the form:

```
Permissions differ on "usr/bin/sudo"; should be -r-s--x--x ; they are -rwxr-xrwx
```

but I left only the filename, the permission it should have and the current permission:

http://pastie.org/9358204

```
Permissions differ on "usr/bin/login"; should be -r-sr-xr-x ; they are -rwxr-xrwx
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the only permission you changed? Is it possible you also removed the `set-userid` permission? The permissions on `/usr/bin/login` should be `-r-sr-xr-x`.

Comment: Post the complete diff output, as text (not as a screenshot). It would be easier to read if the diff output was from inputs in the same format, what you posted seems to list everything (whitespace differences?). Barmar's comment is probably on the right track — if some program should be setuid root but isn't, that program might behave strangely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is indeed that the Finder's way of modifying permissions doesn't only affect the indicated bits as one might think. For some reason it zeroes out the first octal of the file's mode and it leaves the executable bits untouched. So, some vital programs get their [`setuid/setgid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) and [`sticky`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) bits stripped off which makes them either useless or behave erratically.

The setuid bit is needed by some of the programs in `/usr/bin/` because they must interact with the system on a lower level than the usual programs. For example, `sudo`, `passwd`, `newgrp` or `login` need privileges beyond the ones given to an ordinary user and that's why you need a password to execute them. If you remove their setuid bit, they simply can't do their job, which causes them to exit prematurely or even crash.

So, for example, the correct permissions of `/usr/bin/login` are `4555` or `-r-sr-xr-x` and after your friend's manipulation we have `0757` or `-rwxr-xrwx`. The *Terminal.app* calls `/usr/bin/login` to attach your user to a tty (see [`man stty`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/stty.5.html)) and the missing setuid bit causes it to fail. The freeing of an unallocated pointer is probably a bug related to that. On OS X 10.6.8, I don't get this pointer error, but *Terminal.app* quits immediately after starting and I find an entry like `login[6647]: pam_open_session(): system error` in `/var/log/system.log`.

**Edit.** As Antoine Lecaille mentions in a comment, a simple way to make Terminal.app dysfunctional is to issue `$ sudo chmod -s /usr/bin/login`. Note that you can't even open a new window afterwards since this also relies on a call to login. To undo it, just do `$ sudo chmod +s /usr/bin/login`.

---

I tested the Finder's effect on permissions as follows:

```
$ # create a directory with the same permissions as /usr/bin
$ mkdir -m 755 test
$ sudo chown root:wheel test
$ ls -l | grep test
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     wheel    68 Jul  6 15:01 test
$ # create 4096 empty files with all possible permissions
$ cd test
$ sudo touch file_{0..7}{0..7}{0..7}{0..7}
$ for perms in {0..7}{0..7}{0..7}{0..7}; do sudo chmod $perms file_$perms; done
```

The `for` loop may take a minute to complete because `chmod` is slow. After this, you have files `file_wxyz` with permissions `wxyz` in the folder `test`. For example

```
$ ls -l file_4555
-r-sr-xr-x 1 root wheel 0 Jul  6 15:02 file_4555
```

Now we can pull your friend's stunt and change the permissions of the folder and all its contents using the Finder: `$ open .` and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and do what you explained in your post. I decided to grant read permissions to the group wheel and read+write rights to everyone.

Now let's see what happened to our files: The following pipe lists the directory, reads out the column containing the permissions, sorts it and suppresses duplicate lines:

```
$ ls -l | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u
-rw-r--rw-
-rw-r--rwx
-rw-r-xrw-
-rw-r-xrwx
-rwxr--rw-
-rwxr--rwx
-rwxr-xrw-
-rwxr-xrwx
total
$ ls -l file_4555
-rwxr-xrwx 1 root wheel 0 Jul  6 15:02 file_4555
```

As you can see, the setuid/setgid/sticky bits are no longer set; read and write permissions are the same for all files; and the permissions now only differ in their execute bits (of which there are eight possible combinations).

Comment: Thanks. $ sudo chmod -s /usr/bin/login is what causes Terminal.app not to launch.

Comment: @damien, +1. I did not have a real system to check upon when answering this question. I framed my answer mostly on what google had to say. However, you tested and provided the correct answer.Thanks for the answer and I am glad that I also learnt something new. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Short  Answer**

`/usr/bin` contains symbolic links whose permissions will not be modified when you change the permissions on the `/usr/bin` folder and so the permissions are incorrectly set on the symbolic links which causes the pointer to refer to some memory that is inaccessible (As I understand, inaccessible due to **permissions** issue).

**Detailed Answer**

*/bin – User Binaries*

1. Contains binary executables.
2. Common linux commands you need to use in single-user modes are
   located under this directory.
3. Commands used by all the users of the system are located here.
4. For example: ps, ls, ping, grep, cp.

Now, we have changed the permissions on `/usr/bin`. So let us see how the symbolic links permissions are affected.

From [the Wikipedia entry for `Symbolic link`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link):

> The file system permissions of a symbolic link usually have relevance only to rename or removal operations of the link itself, not to the access modes of the target file which are controlled by the target file's own permissions.

So now it is clear that changing permissions on the base file has no impact on the permissions of the symbolic link.

*So what does the error actually mean?*

It means that the code is attempting to free something that was not allocated using `malloc`/`realloc`. Also, what's the point in returning a dead pointer to memory you've freed?

Based on the above observations, I guess that after changing the permissions the symbolic links couldn't be referenced which is why the pointer has become dead (there is no proper permission on the symbolic link). So, you get the above error.

*References*

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575545/pointer-freed-not-allocated
https://superuser.com/questions/303040/how-do-file-permissions-apply-to-symlinks
https://superuser.com/questions/395035/are-world-readable-writable-executable-links-in-usr-bin-security-holes

Comment: Note that the OP mentioned the `chmod` being recursive. In which case, the permissions of the binaries under the folder would also have their executable bits switched off.

Comment: I have no idea how the symlinks and the malloc are related. The files are not less readable than before, just more writeable. Maybe something to do with the system refusing to run world writable binaries for security reason ?  @HalosGhost: the files seem to still be executable.

Comment: Note that on most systems, links always have `777` permissions. Running `chmod` on the link will not affect the link in any way, it will change the permissions _on the target_. The exception seems to be OSX (and presumably BSD and other systems) when `chmod` is run with `-h`. I don't know how Finder changes permissoins internally, whether it calls `chmod()` (the function) internally or executes `chmod` (the program).

Comment: @AntoineLecaille, I suspect the reason you have in your mind might actually be the cause of this error. (i.e) if the files are word writable the system refuses for security reason.

Comment: Most files in `/usr/bin` in OS X are actual binaries, not symbolic links. In particular sudo and login are binaries, so I don't see how this answer is relevant to the actual problem.